# similarities between N900 Maemo 5 OS and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is UBUNTU still the same as MAEMO 5 OS? 
please what's there difference since both of them has .deb file? 
can MAEMO 5 (N900) runs ubuntu's application? &
can UBUNTU runs MAEMO 5 (N900)'s apps too? or are they the same?

am very sorry for the above questions pls, the reason is that this is my first time to use N900 and am not gud in programming especially using X-TERM but i like the phone.

Answer (score 1):

They both use a Linux kernel and the GNU tools and they're both originally based on Debian. But that's about it. They're about as different as two Debian derivatives can possibly be.

- Different graphics (X vs Mir)
- Different UI (Mer vs Unity 8)
- Different application tookits (Largely GTK+ IIRC vs QT5 and HTML5)
- Different packaging (Debs vs Deb for the base system and Click for the user-installed)

Simply put they're wildly different things.

I wouldn't immediately say it's impossible to run one's applications on the other but I wouldn't know where to start.

- Maemo applications are largely just standard Linux applications (compiled for the n900's processor). This is what made the N900 so awesome - most of the Debian archive was available.
- Ubuntu Touch applications seem to tend to be built around the Ubuntu Touch API. This won't naturally be available for Maemo but I guess it could be ported.

Comment: The Nokia N900 was actually using Upstart.
(Just nitpicking, the rest of the reply is still perfectly true :))

Comment: @stgraber I totally didn't notice that at the time. Now I really miss it.